# Finding Nash balances in Pure-strategy Game theory

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am very new to the game theory, however from videos on youtube I have been learning a bit. However, I am not sure how I can apply the knowledge to this question:
`A and B person decide to apply for a job simultaneously. Meanwhile two companies open up a place for only one employee each. Salaries:` $1/2*x < y < 2*x$ `where x and y are companies respectively. If a workplace will have only one applicant, they will hire, otherwise decision will be made at random and the unsuccessful applicant will no longer be able to apply at another company, therefore the benefit would equal to 0, Find all the balances against Nash in pure game strategies`
[image]

I guess I begin this way, however in the $Row1-Col1$ cell I cannot tell which one will be accepted, nor can I say about cell $Row2-Col2$. Also, none of the salaries actually seem larger than the other one, thus how would I know which would be the most desired for these guys. Only I can tell is that most profitable strategies would be $Row1-Col2$ OR $Row2-Col1$.

How should I progress?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Thanks, did it!! In my preview I have nice graph, could you please tell me how can I fix it? $$ did not fix graph... Actually I will try to insert  picture

Comment: As to my knowledge, in game theories they have Person (A) options on x axes and Person (B) option on y axis. I wanted to put these as well, however I am not sure how?

Comment: I don't understand.  If both choose company Y, one person gets $y$ and the other gets $0$.  What is $x/y$  supposed to represent?  The expected payoff to each is $y/2$.  Similarly, in the upper left-hand corner, why is it $x/0$?  Should it not be $(x/2)/(x/2)$?

Comment: Mhh, if the both apply at the same company, one gets accepted and other one gets rejected, in case of which benefit = 0. Therefore I guess the one who gets accepted will have x salary and other one who gets rejected will have 0?

Comment: But we don't know if the one who is accepted will be A or B.  Each has a $50\%$ chance of being the one accepted.

Comment: Mhh, actually yes that is right, But how do I progress next?